# How to pick only a particular set of values from a column and generate an update statement based on that

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a problem where I need to run a set of update statements based on  column values.

So we will get a set of IDs like below after a select query.

```
-------------------------------------
ID   ChangedColumns     ChangedValues         
-------------------------------------
101     col1|col2|    [A^B]|[123^456]|
102      col3|        [XXX^YYY]|
...     ....      ....

and so on
```

Where ChangedColumns are the column names which are changed and ChangedValues will tell the old and new values for the respective columns (delimited by a pipe '|' and enclosed in braces '[]')

Based on this, I need to run update statements on another table, which will be something like

```
update table
set col1='A',
col2='123'
where id = 101;

update table
set col3='XXX'
where id = 102;

update table
.....
..... and so on
```

The number of Changed Columns can be 1 - 20 and its corresponding changed values will be in same order in ChangedValues column.

Could someone please let me know how to write a PL/SQL block for the same?

Many thanks

Comment: I updated my post with a somewhat more refined answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I broke the data down by ID and ChangedColumn:

```
SQL> with tbl(ID, ChangedColumns, ChangedValues) as (
     select 101, 'col1|col2|', '[A^B]|[123^456]|' from dual
     union
     select 102, 'col3|', '[XXX^YYY]|' from dual
   )
   SELECT ID,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedColumns ,'([^|]*)(\|)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) as changedcolumn,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedValues ,'([^|]*)(\|)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) as column_value
        FROM   tbl,
               TABLE(
                 CAST(
                   MULTISET(
                     SELECT LEVEL
                     FROM   DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( ChangedColumns ,'\|' )
                   ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
                 )
               );

        ID CHANGEDCOL COLUMN_VALUE
---------- ---------- ----------------
       101 col1       [A^B]
       101 col2       [123^456]
       102 col3       [XXX^YYY]

SQL>
```

Then changed that to generate a separate update statement for each column that changed for each ID.  The next step is to work it into one update statement for each ID, handling all columns that changed:

```
SQL> with tbl(ID, ChangedColumns, ChangedValues) as (
     select 101, 'col1|col2|', '[A^B]|[123^456]|' from dual
     union
     select 102, 'col3|', '[XXX^YYY]|' from dual
   )
   SELECT 'update table set ' ||
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedColumns, '([^|]*)(\|)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) ||
          ' = ''' ||
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedValues, '\[([^\^]*)(\^)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) ||
          '''' ||
          ' where id = ' || id || ';' as update_stmt
        FROM   tbl,
               TABLE(
                 CAST(
                   MULTISET(
                     SELECT LEVEL
                     FROM   DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( ChangedColumns ,'\|' )
                   ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
                 )
               );

UPDATE_STMT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
update table set col1 = 'A' where id = 101;
update table set col2 = '123' where id = 101;
update table set col3 = 'XXX' where id = 102;

SQL>
```

EDIT:  Here's the final product after some further refining and tweaking:

```
SQL> with tbl_a(ID, ChangedColumns, ChangedValues) as (
    select 101, 'col1|col2|', '[A^B]|[123^456]|' from dual
    union
    select 102, 'col3|', '[XXX^YYY]|' from dual
    union
    select 103, 'col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|', '[XX0^YY0]|[XX1^YY1]|[XX2^YY2]|[XX3^YY3]|[XX4^YY4]|' from dual
  ),
  tbl_b(ID, column_value) as (
  SELECT ID,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedColumns ,'([^|]*)(\|)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) ||
         ' = ' || CHR(39) ||
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(ChangedValues ,'\[([^\^]*)(\^)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) || CHR(39)
       FROM   tbl_a,
              TABLE(
                CAST(
                  MULTISET(
                    SELECT LEVEL
                    FROM   DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( ChangedColumns ,'\|' )
                  ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
                )
              )
  )
  SELECT distinct ID,
     'UPDATE TABLE SET ' || LISTAGG(column_value, ', ')
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id, column_value)
      OVER (PARTITION BY id) || ' WHERE ID = ' || ID || ';' as update_stmt
  FROM tbl_b
  ORDER BY ID;

       ID UPDATE_STMT
--------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      101 UPDATE TABLE SET col1 = 'A', col2 = '123' WHERE ID = 101;
      102 UPDATE TABLE SET col3 = 'XXX' WHERE ID = 102;
      103 UPDATE TABLE SET col4 = 'XX0', col5 = 'XX1', col6 = 'XX2', col7 = 'XX3', col8 = 'XX4' WHERE ID = 103;

SQL>
```

I suspect this could be further simplified, but there's something to be said for breaking a problem down into smaller steps.

Comment: Thanks a ton Gary. This is exactly what I was looking for. You made my day.

Comment: Cool!  If this worked for you please accept it so future searchers will know what worked.

Comment: The final query worked like a charm. I missed this initially that some ChangedValues were NULL. So the update was not working properly. To overcome it, I made below change inside the LISTAGG function. 

     'UPDATE table SET ' || LISTAGG(replace(column_value , '''NULL''' , ''''''), ', ') 
..
..

I accepted the answer just now(didnt know how to do that so googled that too) 

Again thanks a ton for this reply. I learnt at least 4 new functions in Oracle just by this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

Comment: Hi Sarikaya
 Thanks for replying but this is not that I want. The first update statement (for 101) should set col1 and col2 values picked from ChangedValues column. The second update statement should update col3 values derived from corresponding changed values column. The number of ids retured and number of changed columns can very daily. I know we should use some cursors/loop and substr/instr function but not  sure exactly how. Thanks anyways :)